# MacBook Pro seems to consume gmail reminders?

Tags: email, gmail, notifications

Ever since I got my MacBook Pro this year, I do not get any reminders via gmail, to my desktop PC (or Android phone, it seems).

I rely heavily on the reminders so I really do need this to start working.

Every time I wake my MacBook Pro, I notice that my gmail inbox in the browser, as well as my Mail inbox, are full of all the reminders I missed!

So it's almost as if the MBP is "consuming" these. I have wondered if it is Mail's fault, and I've done my best to turn Mail off for good (I only ever use gmail via the browser) but every time I wake the machine, Mail is back again, and my inbox is topped up with all recent reminders. Not sure if this is what's causing my reminders not to go to my desktop / 'droid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Weird: Gmail had, for whatever reason, chosen to begin marking all my calendar event reminders as spam. I find them in my spam folder today, and this had indeed begun just a day or two after I got my MBP. Gmail claimed that it was sent to the spam filter because "It's similar to messages that have been detected by our spam filters." (in the header above the spam-filtered email).

The solution was to explicitly whitelist all google calendar event reminders, [as follows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/why-is-gmail-marking-my-google-calendar-reminders-as-spam).

I also had to clear and reset each of the default notifications for the calendar as [here](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144138).

Now I can get on with my life.